# How to find a particular name repeated how many number of times?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm recieving issue with the output can anyone help me with it?
It is a code for finding how many times a particular name has been repeated.

```
package example1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i,j,t,c;
            String a[]=new String[10];
            String b[]=new String[10];
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                a[i]=sc.nextLine();
                b[i]=a[i];
            }
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                c=0;
                for(j=i+1;j<9;j++)
                {
                    if(b[j]==b[i])
                    {
                        c++;
                        for(t=j;t<10;t++)
                        {
                            b[t]=b[t+1];
                        }
                    }
                }
                 System.out.print(b[i]+" is repeated "+ c +" times ");
               }
            }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the *issue with the output*? What input did you provide? What was the expected output? What did you actually get in the output?

Comment: I provided a set of 10 names, the output i expected is how many times a name has been repeated in that list

Comment: If you're doing string comparison, use `b[j].equals(b[i])`, not `b[j] == b[i]`.

Comment: **or**, `a[i]=sc.nextLine().intern();` if you want to freak out code reviewers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","a","b","c","a","b","a"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list); 
for(String name : set)
    System.out.println(name + " is repeated " + Collections.frequency(list, name) + " times");
```

If you want your comparison to be case insensitive, then try this.

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"A","B","c","D","a","b","c","a","b","a"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(10);
for(String name : arr)
    list.add(name.toLowerCase());
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list); 
for(String name : set)
    System.out.println(name + " is repeated " + Collections.frequency(list, name) + " times");
```

Will require more space though.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help for determining the repetition

```
  public class Repetation {  
        public static void main(String[] args) {  
            String string = "Sam sam is good boy james is sams friend clyra is clyra";  
            int count;   
            string = string.toLowerCase(); 
            String words[] = string.split(" ");  
              
            System.out.println("Duplicate words: ");   
            for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  
                count = 1;  
                for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++) {  
                    if(words[i].equals(words[j])) {  
                        count++; 
                        words[j] = "0";//making it 0  for future reference  
                    }  
                }  
                if(count > 1 && words[i] != "0")  
                    System.out.println(words[i]);  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
    public static int countWord(String input, String text) {
        int index = input.indexOf(text);
        if (index == -1 || text.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        int count = 0;
        do {
            count++;
            index = input.indexOf(text, index + text.length());
        } while (index > 0 && index < input.length());
        return count;
    }
```

This code will return `4`:

```java
int total = countWord("abcs8abc88habcabci7h", "abc");
```